# Count in Reactivemongo with JsObject

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.1, reactivemongo

I'm trying to implement Count on a query but I'm having issues since I do not
work with BSONDocument but with JsObject objects.

https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/samples/SimpleUseCasesSample.scala

Should I translate my JsObject to a BSONDocument or is there a better way?
How would you do this in ReactiveMongo 0.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translate example:

**Service:**

```
  def countSentMailForVenue(currentId: Long, from: DateTime, to: DateTime) : Future[Int] = {
    val query = Json.obj("venueInfo.currentId" -> venueId, "origin" -> Origin.EMAIL_INVITE, "updated" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> from.getMillis, "$lt" -> to.getMillis))
    count(BSONFormats.toBSON(query).get.asInstanceOf[BSONDocument])
  }
```

**And in Dao:**

```
/**
   * Currently Count() only supports BSONDocument.
   */
  def count(query: BSONDocument) : Future[Int] = {
    Logger.debug(s"Counting documents: "+BSONFormats.toJSON(query))
    val futureCount = collection.db.command(
      Count(
        collection.name,
        Some(query)
      )
    )
    futureCount
  }
```